# JSF - typing with regional language

Tags: jsf, input, regional

I created a web application using JSF framework. My application needs some text areas for convert the content into regional language. How it is  possible to done by using google input?. or is there is any other scenario for typing with regional language?

Answer (score -3):

Use [unicode.js](http://ankitpokhrel.com.np/unicode-js/) which is a small and easy to use javascript library to enable native input support in textfields. It uses Google Transliteration API combined with some javascript to enable unicode support in text input fields and textareas or anything where user can type in.